# Why I can't assign nullable type to Any in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, types, null

Can anyone please explain why doing this in Kotlin is impossible?

```
val x :Int? = 123
val y :Any = x
```

I come from .NET background where Nullable type is assignable to Object type, but how are they different?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nullable types are not subtypes of `Any`, but they *are* subtypes of `Any?`.

`Any` is only a superclass of *non-nullable* types. This makes it possible to write code that requires a non-null instance of anything, and still benefit from the safety of the type-checker (unlike when using Java's `Object`).

Here is an image that can help:

[image]

The following code is a valid replacement of yours:

```
val x: Int? = 123
val y: Any? = x
```

Answer (score 4):

From the docs:

> Kotlin's type system is aimed at eliminating the danger of null references from code, also known as the The [Billion Dollar Mistake.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare#Apologies_and_retractions)
>
> In Kotlin, the type system distinguishes between references that can hold null (nullable references) and those that can not (non-null references).

Example:

```
var a: String = "abc"
a = null // compilation error

var b: String? = "abc" //using `String?` allows you to assign null
b = null // ok
print(b)
```

[`Any`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/index.html) is a class same as [`String`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/index.html), the only difference is that every class has `Any` as it's superclass. But the above that I wrote regarding `NPE` is applied to all types in kotlin.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The basic requirement for Kotlin variable is to be marked whether it is Nullable or not to avoid NPE.

Here in your case,

```
var x: Int? = 123
```

is assigned as nullable value with ? but when you mapped it to Any object, you have missed to add nullable ? to Any object

so `var y: Any? = x`

will do as we are marking nullable to y also.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st line of code `val x :Int? = 123` is clearly saying that the x is supposed to hold a value of type `Int`
Kotlin provides the built-in type `Int` that is used to for representing numbers.

On the next line, `val y :Any = x`, y is supposed to hold a type of `Any`, which is the root of the Kotlin class hierarchy. Every Kotlin class has `Any` as a superclass.

So there is type mismatch - and hence Kotlin compiler complains that it cannot assign an `Int` to an object which you declared to hold type `Any`

Comment: "Every Kotlin class has Any as a superclass." This includes `Int`. So you can assign an `Int` to an `Any` without problems, just not an `Int?`.